# Page 2 and up of answers of a deleted question for spam/offensive doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, sorting

### Steps:

1. Earn 10k reputation, so you can see deleted questions.
2. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512 (or any other question that has been deleted for spam/offensiveness)
3. Click or tap "2" in the page selector to visit page 2 of the answers.
   [image: Image of the "page 2" button, as required by the top comment on this question]

### Expected result:

I see page 2 of the answers

### Actual result:

I'm getting a 301 redirect back to the first page again

### Notes:

- The sort-by tabs are also broken
- It works fine with undeleted questions
- It also work fine if the deleted question wasn't deleted for spam/offensive

### Browsers

I can successfully reproduce this in the following 2 browsers:

- Chromium Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit)
- Firefox Quantum 67.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: I thought `press 2` meant the actual key on the keyboard but I see it's actually about clicking the link to page 2. I feel a red circle could have made that even clearer.

Comment: It's a bug, but probably a very rare one. Questions with enough answers to have more than a single page rarely get deleted as spam/offensive, not a clue why Jeff decided it was a good idea to label this one as such.

Comment: I'd recall I've read multiple pages of answers on that specific post just a couple of months ago.

Comment: As a workaround, you can craft your own URL to get to other pages, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512?page=2

Comment: I'd love to test this to confirm. I can haz reps?

Comment: @MattR "bug closed: can't reproduce step 1"

Comment: Can repro on Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169, Win 10 Pro x64 v1809

Comment: Side note: why is that question spam-deleted?

Comment: @AndrasDeak It's highly likely that it is just showing the 'spam deleted' message now because the reason that was used in 2010 for deletion does not exist anymore, or was repurposed in the past into something else that is now under the 'spam or rude/abusive' umbrella. The banner and verbiage shown today for Jeff's delete reason definitely didn't exist back in 2010. My first guess is the reason was something along the lines of "not a real question". Maybe Shog could tell us.

Comment: Duplicate on meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322619/cant-see-other-pages-of-answers-on-a-certain-deleted-question

Comment: @TylerH and AndreasDeak The revision history suggests the close reason was "not a real question" by a group of users, and Jeff Atwood locked and deleted the question shortly after. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17512/revisions

Comment: I just had to. So I might as well share for others: https://web.archive.org/web/20090305232544/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512

Comment: @TylerH Questions that are deleted and locked, and have helpful spam flags are assumed by the system to have been deleted *as spam or abuse* and cause the system to take measures against it (e.g. stripping the title from the URL, not showing related questions in the 404 page shown to <10k users, etc.). Note that the URL stripping logic is a little overzealous and that's what triggers this bug; see the MSE answer I posted (linked above).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be working again. Thanks for the report; if there's one thing 10K users should not be deprived of here, it's an archive of terrible jokes...

Answer (score 2):

Not a 10k+ user here, but we had a similar situation on another site where I *do* have 10k+ reputation. [As I answered there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322621/377214), this happens because one of the "safeguards" that are implemented in the system to prevent spammers from exploiting deleted spam posts is acting a little overzealous.

These "safeguards" include **removing the title from the URL**, suppressing the "related questions" list that normally appears on the 404 page shown to <10k users, and annotating the deletion notice with "this question was deleted as spam or offensive". (Note that the criteria for the "spam mask" is completely different, as it's a completely different mechanism - that only checks for helpful spam flags, not if the post was actually deleted as spam or abuse.)

It's that first part that's the issue: the pagination and sort links consist of full-form URLs that contain the title, and since the system considers *everything* that comes after the post ID as being part of the title, query commands like `?page=2` get stripped out as well, preventing page links from advancing.

As DavidG commented, manually removing the post title from the URL prevents the title stripping logic from taking place, and as such the query command doesn't get stripped out and works normally. (I suggest reading my answer I linked above for a full, technical explanation of how it works.)

As far as this "popular" post being *supposedly* deleted as spam or abuse: this is because the system, when checking to see if the "safeguards" should kick in, uses a very simple check: if the post is deleted, locked, and has helpful spam or abuse flags, they kick in. All of these happen automatically when the post is deleted as spam or offensive, but as you can see, it's possible for this circumstance to be arranged manually. This may be what happened in this case, and is definitely the case if the deletion and lock weren't attributed to the Community user.

**TL;DR**: It's a bunch of rare edge cases coming together to bite. Thankfully, the latest development version of the [SOUP](https://github.com/vyznev/soup) user script contains a (partial) fix for this issue.